# How to get value of custom attribute of product in observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created a sales_order_save_after event observer. i will show the code below

> SalesOrderSaveAfter.php

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{   
    //get the order object
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) 
    {   
        //get status
        $new_status =   $order->getStatus();
        //check the new status is confirm or canceled

        if ($new_status == 'confirm' || $new_status == 'canceled') 
        {    
            //parameters = array()
            $params         =   array();
            $order_id       =   $order->getId();
            $customer_id    =   $order->getCustomerId();

            if( !empty($order_id) ) {
                $product_ids = array();
                foreach( $order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
                    $product_ids[] =    $item->getProductId();
                    $product       =    $item->getData();
                    //$nrv         =    $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('nrv');

                }        
            }


            //$nrv = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_ids)->getAttributeText('nrv');

            $params     =   array(
                'order_id'      =>  $order_id,
                'customer_id'   =>  $customer_id,
                'product_id'    =>  $product_ids,
                'status'        =>  $new_status,
                'product'       =>  $product, 
                //'nrv'         =>  $nrv,
            ); 
        }

        //call the curl
        $this->curlCall($params);

    }
    return $this;
}
```

Everything is working correctly. Am getting All the information except custom attribute. I added custom attribute nrv to each of the product.
but i didn't get value of custom attribute. How can I get the custom attribute value in observer?. Thanks in advance for your valuable answer.

Comment: nrv is custom option?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes It was a custom attribute of the product. I tried with Object manager and got the value. Is there any better method other than object manager?

Comment: I post answer, please check. I will give value of selected custom option with product.

Comment: Try this code: $product       =    $item->getProduct();
  $nrvAttribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('nrv');
 echo  $nrvAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

Answer (score 6):

**Try following code:**

> 1. Attribute without custom options

```
$value = $item->getProduct()->getData('attribute_code');
```

> 2. Attribute with custom options

```
$optionId = $item->getProduct()->getData('attribute_code');

$optionValue = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
```

OR

```
$optionValue = $item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());
```

**Check output in log file using following code:**

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Option Value: ', $optionValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get custom option value of product using this code in observer,

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

    if(array_key_exists("attributes_info",$options) && count($options['attributes_info']) >= 1) :

       // THis code give all the custom attribute value
       foreach($options['attributes_info'] as $myopt)
       {
            echo $myopt['label']." : ".$myopt['value']; 
       }

     endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try by Factory Method:**

```
protected $request;
protected $productFactory;  

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,

) { 
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;


/**
 *
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
    foreach( $order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()
            ->load($item->getProductId());
        echo $product->getNrv();
    } 
}
```

After run compile command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $product_data = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_ids);
                    $nrv = $product_data->getData('nrv');
```

Atlast i got the answer by using object manager.